# Flutter : WillPopScope onWillPop is not working with device back button press

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, back, onbackpressed

In my flutter application I have 3 screens 'HomeScreen' -> 'TeamSetup' -> 'ManagePreference'. I have implemented WillPopScope onWillPop method on TeamSetup & ManagePreference but its not calling when I press the device back button, and both the back button press leads to HomeScreen, but I need to get back to TeamSetup screen on ManagePreference back button click. Everything works fine when I use the appbar back button.

Issue : onWillPop not calling on back press,hence code on onWillPop will not work.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
HomeScreen({Key? key,required this.user}) : super(key: key);
final User user;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
        appBar: customAppBar,
        body: SafeArea(
            .....

            child:PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (value) {
                Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TeamSetup(user: user, item: itemList[index]),
                ));
            },
            ),

            .....
        ),
        ),
    );
}
}


class TeamSetup extends StatefulWidget {
final User user;
final dynamic item;
const TeamSetup({Key? key, required this.user,required this.item}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<TeamSetup> createState() => _TeamSetupState();
}

class _TeamSetupState extends State<AccountSetup> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: onBackPress,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: customAppBar,
        .....

        child:PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (value) {
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ManagePreference(user: user, team: teamList[index]),
            ));
            },
        ),

        .....
        ),
    ),
    );
}

Future<bool> onBackPress() {
    //  Not working
    Navigator.pop(context);
    return Future.value(false);
    }
}

class ManagePreference extends StatefulWidget {
    .....
}

class _ManagePreferenceState extends State<ManagePreference> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: customAppBar,
        .....
        .....
        ),
    ),
    );
}

Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    // Not working  
    // This dialog will exit your app on saying yes
    return (await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
        actions: <Widget>[
        new ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: new Text('No'),
        ),
        new ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
            child: new Text('Yes'),
        ),
        ],
    ),
    )) ?? false;
}
}

CustomAppBar(BuildContext context,double screenHeight,String title,String subTitle) {
PreferredSizeWidget customAppBar = AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    leading: IconButton(
    onPressed: (){
        // working correctly
        Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
    //replace with our own icon data.
    ),
    ....
);

return customAppBar;
}
```

Comment: Try this instead.   onWillPop:()=> onBackPress ()  & onWillPop:()=>_onWillPop()

Comment: that doesn't have any difference

Answer (score -1):

you need to create a function

```
DateTime? currentBackPressTime;
Future<bool> onWillPop() {
FocusScope.of(Get.context!).requestFocus(FocusNode());
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
now.difference(currentBackPressTime!) > const 
Duration(seconds: 3)) {
currentBackPressTime = now;
log("press again to exit");
return Future.value(false);
}
return exit(0);
}
```

and then call it on your class where you want to click back.

```
 body: WillPopScope(
 onWillPop: onWillPop,)
```

Comment: onWillPop not calling on back press